# EF4 Code First make tables names singular

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm using standards for singular table names. EF4 Code First has by default to pluralize table names. I have put the code to override this convention, but seems is not working.

using section:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Database;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.Edm;
```

Data context:

```
public class SiteDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BlogFeedback> BlogFeedbacks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BlogCategory> BlogCategories { get; set; }

        // Twist our database
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Tables created:

- Blogs
- BlogFeedbacks
- BlogCategories

When because the convention override (and what I need) should be:

- Blog
- BlogFeedback
- BlogCategory

Anyone has an idea why the override line is not working? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your using the wrong convention. You need to do the below.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Comment: That was a good one! You are right, I changed and now is working! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that in EF5 the parameter type is DbModelBuilder

Comment: Dude, Thanks a ton. Right on the nail.

Comment: +1: Useful, pointed me in the right direction.
-1: Incomplete: `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention`

Answer (score 0):

I our current project we had the same problem. I wrote about it in another question, but here it is:

[Entity Framework v4 and underscores in column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479674/entity-framework-v4-and-underscores-in-column-names/5480244#5480244)

It's a little more complex than expected.

HTH