# Making Visual Studio 2012 generate singular table names from a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I created a Model for a database table in Visual Studio 2012, and then I generated a Controller class and some Views (Create.cshtml, Edit.cshtml, etc.) using Entity Framework. But the generation tool pluralizes the table name. My table name is Person, and the generated table name is Persons.

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio to generate a singular table name?

Comment: There is a way around it.  Code and explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969187/why-does-ef-5-x-use-plural-name-for-table

Answer (score 1):

override the OnModelCreating method and add:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

If you are using the ADO.NET Entity Data Model wizard, on the last page where you select your tables there is a checkbox for this option also.  It's pretty annoying that it doesn't default to using your table names as they are in the database

Comment: will not work for EF6, where mapping api is not public