# ASP.NET - Invalid object name 'dbo.ForumSections'

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to read data from my database. I have created a table called ForumSections, here is its table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ForumSection] (
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (0, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SectionName]        NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [TopicsinSection]      INT            NOT NULL,
    [SectionDescription] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

When I try to call from the database I get a EntityCommandExecutionException with a InnerException message of Invalid object name 'dbo.ForumSections'.

Here is the code used to call the database.
First setting up the database context:

```
public class MainDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MainDbContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    { 
    }
    public DbSet<ForumSection> ForumSection { get; set; }
}
```

Then calling it:

```
var db = new MainDbContext();
db.ForumSection.Find(0); //Error happens on this line
```

The row with index of 0 is appropriately filled out.
What are my options for resolving this?

Comment: could you solve your problem?

Comment: Consider if there is a connection issue or an ORM issue as each may be possible here.

Answer (score 1):

By default, EntityFramework tries to look for the table pluralizing the name of the class. That's why it is adding the 's' to the ForumSection.

You can disable that option. This will help you solve your problem:

[Why does EF 5.x use plural name for table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969187/why-does-ef-5-x-use-plural-name-for-table)