# Entityframework Code First Singularize table name

Tags: entity-framework

I've tried the way it's mentioned in 
[EF4 Code First make tables names singular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898661/ef4-code-first-make-tables-names-singular) but in my case EF6 is not recognizing OnModelCreating(). It says "No suitable method found to override". Is there any alternate way or any way to fix it?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain of the ModelBuilder Type but I can say for a fact I just tested my older Code First on EF 6.1.3 and it works fine with this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    ...
}
```

I think you needed **Db**ModelBuilder versus ModelBuilder.  I am not sure of that thread but know I just ran mine just now and that was the only thing I noticed differently.  I learned EF Code First from two tutorials and this one by far was better than the other by leaps and bounds: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx

Comment: DbModelBuilder works well. djangojazz, thanks for your time responding.

Comment: np, happy coding